# How can I apply interaction between two variable for multiple non-linear regression with GAM?

Tags: r, non-linear-regression, gam

I have a data with Y and X1, X2 which has different dimension, like X1 = xxxx Volt, X2 = xx hour.

To make regression model with this data, I used code below.

```
MODEL <- gam(Y ~ s(X1) + s(X2), data = DATA, method = "REML")
```

It seems to work well, but I want apply a interaction between X1 and X2 to my code.

Could I do the multiple non-linear regression with using a code like :

```
MODEL <- gam(Y ~ s(X1) + s(X2) + ti(X1, X2), data = DATA, method = "REML")
```

or should I use different equation to do this work?

Comment: I read this topic a while ago. Does it help? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32730/how-to-include-an-interaction-term-in-gam

Comment: Topic you shared help me to solve the te() function problem with other direction. Thank you for your comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred way would be:

```r
MODEL <- gam(Y ~ te(X1, X2), data = DATA, method = "REML")
```

as that entails selection of fewer smoothness parameters so it is a slightly simpler version of the model you showed.

However, if you want to see if the interaction is significant or otherwise want to separate out the main effects from the interaction, then yes, the model you showed is the way to go

```
MODEL <- gam(Y ~ s(X1) + s(X2) + ti(X1, X2), data = DATA, method = "REML")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I use the code : te(X1, X2), could I apply all relations? (including X1, X2 to Y and interaction between X1, X2)

Comment: Yes, the `te()` smooth contains the main effects *and* the interaction

Comment: Thank you so much, it is really helpful for my work :)